# Getting data from Humminbird ChartSelect .bin file

Tags: python, bathymetry

I purchased some lake bathymetry data from humminbird chartselect. I can see those data using their applications such as FishSmart or also using the humminbird sonar module. But I would like to read those data as a CSV file with X, Y, Depth values. Is there any way to do so?

Here I'm attaching the screenshot of the data in their application. [image]

Also, the file looks like this[image]
Also, one of the bin file [image]

Comment: You have a tag for Python.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.